# input要素を含んだ配列を削除する際、削除するinputのvalueも削除したい

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ユーザー側で項目を増減できるテキストフォーム入りリストを作成しています。
下記はデモです。
Reactを使用しています。
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-austin-nxpku?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
リスト直下の`Add item`を押すことで、リスト追加できます。
リストの右端の`×`を押すことで、リストを削除できます。

現状リストの増減はできるようになったのですが、テキストフォームに値を入力した状態で入力したリストを削除すると、リストは削除できるものの、フォームの値が削除されない状態です。
[image: gif]

リストの左端`Number`の値は識別子ではなくリストの数を表現したいので`Number`の値は変わらなくてよいのですが、フォームの値は削除したいです。

---

下記がコードです。

```js
export default function App() {
　const defaultItem = { a: "", b: "", c: "" };
  const [items, setItems] = useState([defaultItem]);
  const [length, setLength] = useState(1);

  const addItem = () => {
    if (length > 4) return;
    setItems((items) => [...items, defaultItem]);
    setLength((length) => length + 1);
  };
  const deleteItem = ({ target: { name } }) => {
    const newItemArray = [...items];
    newItemArray.splice(Number(name), 1);
    setItems(newItemArray);
    setLength((length) => length - 1);
  };

  const itemList = items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{index + 1}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="a" defaultValue={item.a} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="a" defaultValue={item.b} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="a" defaultValue={item.c} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={deleteItem} name={index.toString()}>
            ×
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  const submitList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitList}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{itemList}</tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={addItem} disabled={length > 4 ? true : false}>
        Add item
      </button>
      <hr />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

リストの削除は下記の関数です。

```js
const deleteItem = ({ target: { name } }) => {
  const newItemArray = [...items];
  newItemArray.splice(Number(name), 1);
  setItems(newItemArray);
  setLength((length) => length - 1);
};
```

リスト削除ボタンの`name`属性にリストの`index`番号を設定して、削除ボタン押下時に`name`属性からリストの番号を取得し、該当する番号のリストを削除する、という処理を狙っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リストと key – React
https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

> 要素の並び順が変更される可能性がある場合、インデックスを key として使用することはお勧めしません。パフォーマンスに悪い影響を与え、コンポーネントの状態に問題を起こす可能性があります。Robin Pokorny による、[key としてインデックスを用いる際の悪影響](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)についての詳しい解説をご覧ください。より詳しく学びたい場合は、[key が何故必要なのかについての詳しい解説](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)を参照してください。

Index as a key is an anti-pattern (React) | by Robin Pokorny | Medium
https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

> Many people asked if they always, *always* have to generate ids. Others have suggested use cases when using the index as a key seems justifiable.
>
> It is true that sometimes generating new ids is redundant and may be avoided. For example translation of license terms or list of contributors.
>
> To help you decide, I put together three conditions which these examples have in common:
>
> 1. the list and items are static–they are not computed and do not change;
> 2. the items in the list have no ids;
> 3. the list is never reordered or filtered.

---

今回のコード例のリストは `the list and items are static–they are not computed and do not change` ではないので、 `item` それぞれに固有の識別子が必要です。

実際のアプリケーションコードでそれぞれの `item` に使用できそうな識別子があれば、それを利用してください。

実際のコードでも識別子がない場合、[nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/)などのライブラリを使って識別子の生成を検討してください。

以下のコードは識別子に `new Date().getTime()` を使用した例になります。
(回答の為のサンプルコードとして使用しています。私が `new Date().getTime()` の使用を**推奨しているわけではない**ことに注意してください)

```js
function App() {
  const defaultItem = () => ({ id: new Date().getTime(), a: "", b: "", c: "" });
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([defaultItem()]);
  const [length, setLength] = React.useState(1);

  const addItem = () => {
    if (length > 4) return;
    setItems((items) => [...items, defaultItem()]);
    setLength((length) => length + 1);
  };
  const deleteItem = ({ target: { name } }) => {
    const newItemArray = [...items];
    newItemArray.splice(Number(name), 1);
    setItems(newItemArray);
    setLength((length) => length - 1);
  };

  const itemList = items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{index + 1}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="a" defaultValue={item.a} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="a" defaultValue={item.b} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="a" defaultValue={item.c} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={deleteItem} name={index.toString()}>
            ×
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  const submitList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitList}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{itemList}</tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={addItem} disabled={length > 4 ? true : false}>
        Add item
      </button>
      <hr />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。希望通りの挙動になりました。